# How can I install a library (cfgrib) in databricks through conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, databricks, cfgrib, eccodes

I'm trying to install cfgrib (https://pypi.org/project/cfgrib/) on databricks.

Cfgrib depends only on the c-library eccodes.

I installed both eccodes and cfgrib through the libraries page of databricks.
However, when I do "import cfgrib", it keeps on saying:
"Cannot find the ecCodes library"

On cfgrib package page, they say the best way to install it is via conda with:
$ conda install -c conda-forge cfgrib

Months ago with an older runtime version of the cluster (that I don't have anymore) I managed to install it throgh conda writing direcly on the databricks notebook: "%sh conda install -c conda-forge eccodes"

However when I try to do the same now it keeps running for like 1 hour and doesn't install it.

How can I install it?
Is there a way to install conda libraries on the cluster itself and not in the notebook?

Thank you very much,

(my first question, any feedback is welcomed :)

Comment: I guess you have to define where the software was installed and set some of eccodes env. variables correctly https://sites.ecmwf.int/docs/eccodes/group__environment.html

Comment: Have you succeded somehow?